# React onLoad callback should set state of element, but does not do so, because onLoad is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a load of custom checkboxes that look like this:

```
<CustomCheckbox className='' name='foo' text='Foo' defaultState={false} onChange={this.handleChange} onLoad={this.handleChange}/>
```

Which are components of this form:

```
export const CustomCheckbox = (props) => {
  return (
    <label htmlFor={props.name} className={`customCheckboxLabel ${props.className}`}>
      <input type='checkbox' name={props.name} id={props.name} className='customCheckboxInput' onChange={props.onChange} onLoad={props.onLoad} defaultChecked={props.defaultState}/>
      <span>{props.text}</span>
    </label>
  )
}
```

onChange:

```
handleChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.checked })
```

In terms of `onChange`, this works fine, however, onLoad is not being called. I actually want onChange and onLoad to be the same function, as that way, the checkboxes will automatically populate the state with their (initially unchecked) values, and update them to checked if the user checks them.

The reason I want to do this, is that I later need to submit the whole checkbox array (both checked and unchecked). The number and values of checkboxes are likely to be changed regularly, so I don't want to have to define `foo: false` for every checkbox in the constructor of the page, as this seems to violate DRY (and would be a pain, since adding a checkbox would mean adding the component, *and* adding it to the initial state)

Desired behaviour:

handleChange called when each checkbox initially loads, so that the state contains `name: initialstate` for every checkbox, handleChange called again on change, to record if checkbox state is changed from initialstate.

Current behaviour:

onLoad function is never called.

Comment: checkboxes/inputs do not have a load event.

Comment: Oh... Is there a way around that?

Comment: I guess I could change the CustomCheckbox to a class based component instead, and use the componentDidMount, but that seems like overkill